# An unexpected SQLSelectCountMismatchException occurs

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have been complaining that I must check the Hibernate queries with my eyes without automation. That's why I am fascinated by the library called [Hypersistence Utils](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils) by vladmihalcea.

But here is the problem. I am unable to use its methods. I use Kotlin Spring Boot.
Below is the source code:

Entity

```
@Entity
class Book(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0L,
)
```

Repository

```
interface BookRepository : JpaRepository<Book, Long>
```

Service

```
@Service
class DemoService(
    private val bookRepository: BookRepository,
) {
    @Transactional
    fun a() {
        bookRepository.findById(0)
    }
}
```

Finally, test code

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestConstructor(autowireMode = ALL)
internal class DemoServiceTest(
    private val demoService: DemoService,
) {
    @Test
    fun a() {
        reset()
        demoService.a()
        assertSelectCount(1)
    }
}
```

This test gives me a failing result with the message below:

```
Expected 1 statements but recorded 0 instead!
com.vladmihalcea.sql.exception.SQLSelectCountMismatchException: Expected 1 statements but recorded 0 instead!
```

What I don't understand is that, the service method `a()` under test is transactional one but the `assertSelectCount()` method does not detect the query having been executed.

Here are the logs:

```
[    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select book0_.id as id1_0_0_ from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
[    Test worker] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [0]
```

Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was data proxy that I missed.

Below codes are needed to pass the test method `a()`. I have found this [here](https://arnoldgalovics.com/spring-boot-datasource-proxy/).

```
@Component
class DatasourceProxyBeanPostProcessor : BeanPostProcessor {
    override fun postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean: Any, beanName: String): Any {
        return bean
    }

    override fun postProcessAfterInitialization(bean: Any, beanName: String): Any {
        return if (bean is DataSource) {
            ProxyDataSourceBuilder.create(bean)
                .logQueryBySlf4j(INFO)
                .multiline()
                .countQuery()
                .build()
        } else bean
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working integration of vladmihalcea's db-util in the github project [Ancarian/Facluties](https://github.com/Ancarian/Faculties/) in Spring Boot Test. Adding this Component adds the required listener to the datasource used in your Junit Test : [DatasourceProxyBeanPostProcessor.java](https://github.com/Ancarian/Faculties/blob/master/server/dao/src/test/java/dev/chermenin/dao/DatasourceProxyBeanPostProcessor.java)